# GWT-Objectify : basic

Tags: gwt, objectify

I've been through a few documentations, but am not able to communicate to the datastore yet...can anyone give me a sample project/code of objectify used in GWT web app(I use eclipse)...just a simple 'put' and 'get' action using RPC should do...or, atleast tell me how its done

Comment: GWT Objectify documentation is pretty comprehensive and should help you get started quickly. Is your problem related to objectify or in getting the basic GWT client-server RPC right?

Comment: yea...but i get this error myproject/servlet not found even after making all changes to the xml, java and al

Comment: I'm quite new to GWT and there is something I always tend to forget/have a hard time finding when adding a new dependency: the correct inheritance line for gwt.xml. For Objectify: <inherits name="com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify" />

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to understand how to make objectify work is to repeat all steps described in [this article](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/simplify-with-objectify/) from David's Chandler blog. Whole blog is a pretty much must read if you interested in GWT, GAE(Java), gwt-presenter, gin\guice,etc. There you will find working example, but anyway here i'll show a slighly advanced example.

In package `shared` define your entity/model:

```
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Unindexed;

@Entity
public class MyEntry implements IsSerializable {
    // Objectify auto-generates Long IDs just like JDO / JPA
    @Id private Long id;
    @Unindexed private String text = "";
    @Embedded private Time start;

    // empty constructor for serialization
    public MyEntry () {
    }
    public MyEntry (Time start, String text) {
        super();
        this.text = tText;
        this.start = start;
    }
    /*constructors,getters,setters...*/
}
```

Time class (also `shared` package) contains just one field msecs:

```
@Entity  
public class Time implements IsSerializable, Comparable<Time> {
protected int msecs = -1;    
  //rest of code like in MyEntry 
}
```

Copy class `ObjectifyDao` from link above to your `server.dao` package. And then make DAO class specifically for MyEntry -- MyEntryDAO:

```
package com.myapp.server.dao;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.myapp.shared.MyEntryDao;

public class MyEntryDao extends ObjectifyDao<MyEntry>
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyEntryDao.class.getName());

    static
    {
        ObjectifyService.register(MyEntry.class);
    }

    public MyEntryDao()
    {
        super(MyEntry.class);
    }

}
```

Finally we can make requests to database(`server` package):

```
public class FinallyDownloadingEntriesServlet extends HttpServlet {
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws
ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
                //more code...
                resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+"MyFileName"+".txt\";");
        try {
            MyEntryDao = new MyEntryDao();
          /*query to get all MyEntries from datastore sorted by start Time*/
            ArrayList<MyEntry> entries = (ArrayList<MyEntry>) dao.ofy().query(MyEntry.class).order("start.msecs").list();

            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            int i = 0;
            for (MyEntry entry : entries) {
                ++i;
                out.println(i);
                out.println(entry.getStart() + entry.getText());
                out.println();
            }
        } finally {
            //catching exceptions
        }
    }
```